# How to "mask" url link in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a dynamic page at the root of the app router.
Works.

But I want to create a permalink structure like:

`domain.com/[slug]/[slug]/`

The first slug will stay there as a prefix or decorator, second slug will pull data.

The problem is, that the first slug will be triggered by the dynamic root page [slug], my idea is to create a `rewrites` case, to change the user destination.

Ideally will be to rewrite the destination from `domain.com/[slug]/[slug]/` to `domain.com/category/[slug]/[slug]`without changing the permalink structure.

How to tell `<Link>` component to do this?